# My query using Drupal's db_select is only getting one item, should be getting variable

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

So I am making a Drupal query using the db_select query.

I am trying to get the last $i values, but I am only getting the last value. Here's my code:

```
$query = db_select('registration');

$result = $query
->fields('registration', array('registration_id'))
->orderBy('registration_id', 'DESC')
->range(0, $i)
->execute()
->fetchAssoc();
```

Note, $i is set earlier in the program, and delivers the correct result when I check it.

Comment: i hope you are not trying to get the largest registration_id then increment it to be used as the id for a new row.

Comment: Try setting a static value for $i and then check what actual value is used for $i

Answer (score 1):

The `fetchAssoc()` method only fetches the *next* row. To get the full result set you can iterate through all of the results like so:

```
$result = $query
->fields('registration', array('registration_id'))
->orderBy('registration_id', 'DESC')
->range(0, $i)
->execute();

while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    // do something
}
```

However, since you are only selecting a single field I think a better fetch type might be `fetchCol()`.  If you simply replace the `fetchAssoc()` with `fetchCol()` in your query `$results` will equal a zero-indexed array of all results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the whole while loop deal you can just use the `fetchAll()` call.

```
$events = db_select('registration', 'r')
->fields('registration', array('registration_id'))
->orderBy('registration_id', 'DESC')
->range(0, $i)
->execute()
->fetchAll();
```